# POSTGRES - change value of parameters to oposite

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got table with parameters (varchar) and some of parameters should be equal only 1 or 0. I want to change this parameters to opposite without knowing of old value.
In Mysql I used trick

```
UPDATE `parameters` SET `val`=(val^1) WHERE `name` = xxx
```

but how to do this in postgres?

Answer (score 2):

Use `-` if the parameter is a number:

```
update parameters
    set val = 1 - val
    where name = xxx;
```

Use `case` logic if the parameter is a string:

```
update parameters
    set val = (case when val = '0' then '1' else '0' end)
    where name = xxx;
```

This guarantees that the result is 0/1, even if -- for some reason -- the existing value is different.

Comment: SQL Error [42883]: integer - character varying

Comment: val = 1 - NULLIF(val, '')::int is the solution

Comment: @WuBe . . . Use the `case` expression.  `^` is a bitwise XOR, suggesting that the type in MySQL is *not* a character (based on your description of how the code works).

Answer (score 1):

if parameters is an integer subtract 1 and then apply the absolute function
ie

update parameters set val = abs(val - 1) where name = xxx

any 1 will become = 0,  any 0 becomes = 1

Answer (score 1):

Solution is:

```
UPDATE parameters SET val = 1 - NULLIF(val, '')::int WHERE
```

Comment: or even better val = 1 - val::int